# Question About seting MS Access Relationship type

Tags: ms-access-2007, relationship

I have two tables A,B like

A(A_pk_id,A_name), B(A_pk_id,B_pk_id,B_Name);

Here A_pk_id is primary key of table A, And table B has composite primary key comprising of two fields A_pk_id(Table's primary key),B_pk_id,

Now whenever i tried to define relationship between these two tables [on A_pk_id] MS Access 2007 set their relationship type 1 to 1, but i want it to be 1 to many, cardinality of table must be set to 1.

Can any body guide how i could accomplish my goal.

Regards
Ahsan

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a 1:1 relationship, it means you're joining two fields that both have a unique index on them (regardless of whether both are PK or not). The many side needs to have a non-unique index.